# Consistently modifying multiple columns and multiple rows without explicit transactions

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

A brief introduction to my problem: I have a table `Flags` and a table `SubmittedFlags`, where the former contains flags (which have an owner) and the latter contains flag submissions from attackers:

```
public class SubmittedFlag
{
    public long FlagId { get; set; }
    public long AttackerTeamId { get; set; }
    public long RoundId { get; set; }
    public long SubmissionsCount { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

`SubmissionsCount` should track how many times a given team tried to (re)submit a certain flag, so we may punish teams who don't filter their submissions for duplicates.

Since the scoring formula weights every flag individually, I have to use different queries while calculating the defense and offense points, and because I want it to perform with huge numbers of flags, every query would require a distinct multi-column index which I'd like to avoid (there are multiple WHERE and GROUP BY clauses in different orders).

Can I consistently do batched operations that both

- INSERT OR UPDATE a new `SubmittedFlag` (insert with `SubmissionsCount` 1, or increment the value)
- UPDATE the corresponding `Flag` (increment a new `Captures` column)

without resorting to explicit transactions which cause locked rows or even tables between the SELECT and UPDATE statements? I assume using concurrency tokens won't work because the INSERT OR UPDATEs will execute no matter if the UPDATEs successfully updated a row.

I hope my worries are unduly and I will try out how explicit transactions perform and what ranges of rows or complete tables they lock, but I am curious whether a pseudo "lock-free" way of consistently updating distinct columns exists. I suspect there isn't, but maybe someone knows?

Comment: "UPDATE the corresponding Flag (increment a new Captures column)" I think you need to show us your table definitions, not your class definitions.  What is "flag"?  What is "Captures"?  Neither of those is clear from your class definition.

Comment: "explicit transactions which cause locked rows"  Implicit transactions also cause locked rows.  Implicit single-statement transactions which effect multiple rows can still block and deadlock each other.  If you think implicit transactions will make you immune from those things, you are going down the wrong path.

Comment: A flag is just a bunch of ints (roundId, ownerId, serviceId and an offset), and captures would be a new int column which tracks the amount of corresponding SubmittedFlags entries - sorry if that wasn't clear. Implicit transactions cause locks, but I they don't cause locks that are held during a SELECT - UPDATE cycle (?)